# CSS aspect-ratio fallback

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

**I am trying to support an older browser with a padding-based css ratio fallback.**

I have a container that I expect to default to 16/9 ratio with the following markup, however the height is not matching expectation. In the below instance it should be 720px high but it is rendering at 987px (which I assume is based on my browser window).

```
.ratio {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 1280px;
  padding: 0 0 56.25% 0;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #555;
}
```

I have created a pen to illustrate, can anyone spot the issue?

https://codepen.io/ozorchard/pen/yLpodEb

Note: I have followed the structure from previously flagged answers.
[Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Comment: Padding in percentage applies to the width of the containing block, and that is `.container` in your example (which should be fully contained within your question, btw., see [mre].)

Comment: Ehm, but if you hardcode the width to `1280` why can't you hardcode the height to `720`?